# I have a list which copies itself or appends itself every time I run my program and I really don't understand (python with opencv)

Tags: python, list, opencv

I'm actually coding a Multitracker with Opencv using a CSRT tracker. (I used a online code and modified it as I need, here is the source: https://learnopencv.com/multitracker-multiple-object-tracking-using-opencv-c-python/ )
Every time a bounding box is 'updated' its coordinates are added to a list.

For every bbox (bounding box) I have to lists, one for the x and y coordinates of the top left corner of the bbox, and an other one for the x and y coordinates of the bottom right corner. (Those lists are respectively called p1 and p2.)

I have done almost everything that I want, but the p2 list of the bbox 1 don't stop copying itself or something like in the p2 list of the third bbox, and it don't depend of how much bbox exists.
Note that I don't want any comments about improving it or optimizing it I don't care about it.
Note too that the program is made to run with up to 6 bbox, and it's normal I don't need more but the program can run with 1, 2, or least that 6 bbox if I want.

If I'm lucky it's a stupid error, but I can't get it, so maybe that looks from other peoples on it may find it better than I can! ^^

Here is my long, unoptimized and ugly program! (And thanks if you help me!):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import cv2
import time
from random import randint


#here we're asking data to calculate the number of frames the program will have to show while measuring bounding boxes coordinates and mensuration
framespersecond = int(input("Please enter the framerate of your video/camera per second (without unities please):"))
time.sleep(0.5)
print("Thanks.")
time.sleep(0.5)
timeplayed = int(input("Now, please enter the time you want it to run:(If you wont run a certain amount of time, please enter 0.)"))
if timeplayed == 0:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    numbofframes = int(input("Oh. Please enter the number of frames you want to play:"))
else:
    numbofframes = timeplayed*framespersecond

#we create some of the lists we'll need, the first one to know how much bounding boxes were created and the others for coordinates
bboxnumber = 0
bboxescoord1p1 = []
bboxescoord1p2 = []
bboxescoord2p1 = []
bboxescoord2p2 = []
bboxescoord3p1 = []
bboxescoord3p2 = []
bboxescoord4p1 = []
bboxescoord4p2 = []
bboxescoord5p1 = []
bboxescoord5p2 = []
bboxescoord6p1 = []
bboxescoord6p2 = []

#this timer is for when we use the 'camera' calculation method instead of the video calculation method
#time.sleep(5)

# Set video to load
videoPath = "python-bouncing-ball-simulator-5_V9F95rFx_JQ0y(1).mp4"
#0=intérieure 1=extérieure
#videoPath = 0

# Create a video capture object to read videos
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath)

# Read first frame
success, frame = cap.read()
# quit if unable to read the video file
if not success:
    print('Failed to read video')
    sys.exit(1)

trackerTypes = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL', 'KCF','TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']
def createTrackerByName(trackerType):
    # Create a tracker based on tracker name
    if trackerType == trackerTypes[0]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerBoosting_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[1]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMIL_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[2]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerKCF_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[3]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerTLD_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[4]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[5]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerGOTURN_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[6]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[7]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerCSRT_create()
    else:
        tracker = None
        print('Incorrect tracker name')
        print('Available trackers are:')
        for t in trackerTypes:
            print(t)

    return tracker

## Select boxes
bboxes = []
colors = [] 

# OpenCV's selectROI function doesn't work for selecting multiple objects in Python
# So we will call this function in a loop till we are done selecting all objects
while True:
  # draw bounding boxes over objects
  # selectROI's default behavior is to draw box starting from the center
  # when fromCenter is set to false, you can draw box starting from top left corner
  bbox = cv2.selectROI('MultiTracker', frame)
  bboxes.append(bbox)
  bboxnumber +=1
  colors.append((randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))
  print("Press q to quit selecting boxes and start tracking")
  print("Press any other key to select next object")
  k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
  if (k == 113):  # q is pressed
        print(f"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        break

print('Selected bounding boxes {}'.format(bboxes))



# Specify the tracker type
trackerType = "CSRT"        

# Create MultiTracker object
multiTracker = cv2.legacy.MultiTracker_create()

# Initialize MultiTracker
for bbox in bboxes:
    multiTracker.add(createTrackerByName(trackerType), frame, bbox)

whereami = 1
whereamitot= 0
    # Process video and track objects
for i in range(numbofframes):
    success, frame = cap.read()
    if not success:
        break

    # get updated location of objects in subsequent frames
    success, boxes = multiTracker.update(frame)

    # draw tracked objects
    for i, newbox in enumerate(boxes):
        whereamitot+=1
        p1 = (int(newbox[0]), int(newbox[1]))
        p2 = (int(newbox[0] + newbox[2]), int(newbox[1] + newbox[3]))
        cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, colors[i], 2, 1)

        #define in which list we will put data depending on which bounding box we are 'looking' at
        #p1 are the coordinates of the top left corner and p2 the coordinates of the the bottom right corner
        if whereami ==1:
            bboxescoord1p1.append(p1)
            bboxescoord1p2.append(p2)
            print("---------------------------------")
        elif whereami ==2:
            bboxescoord2p1.append(p1)
            bboxescoord2p2.append(p2)
            print("SHEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEESsh")
        elif whereami ==3:
            print("lblblbl")
            bboxescoord3p1.append(p1)
            bboxescoord3p2.append(p2)
        elif whereami ==4:
            bboxescoord4p1.append(p1)
            bboxescoord4p2.append(p2)
        elif whereami ==5:
            bboxescoord5p1.append(p1)
            bboxescoord5p2.append(p2)
        elif whereami ==6:
            bboxescoord6p1.append(p1)
            bboxescoord6p2.append(p2)

        #define next lists to fill with data depending of the number of bounding boxes and depending of where in the list list we already are (this is not optimized but who cares?)
        if bboxnumber ==1:
            whereami =1
        elif bboxnumber ==2:
            if whereami == 1:
                whereami+=1
            elif whereami==2:
                whereami=1
            else:
                print("Error in the whereami 2nd section.")
        elif bboxnumber==3:
            if whereami<3:
                whereami+=1
            elif whereami==3:
                whereami=1
            else:
                print("Error in the whereami 3nd section.")
        elif bboxnumber==4:
            if whereami<4:
                whereami+=1
            elif whereami==4:
                whereami=1
            else:
                print("Error in the whereami 4th section.")
        elif bboxnumber==5:
            if whereami<5:
                whereami+=1
            elif whereami==5:
                whereami=1
            else:
                print("Error in the whereami 5th section.")
        elif bboxnumber==6:
            if whereami<6:
                whereami+=1
            elif whereami==6:
                whereami=1
            else:
                print("Error in the whereami 6th section.")
        else:
            print("Error in the 'whereami/bboxnumber' section.")
        


    
    # show frame
    cv2.imshow('MultiTracker', frame)
    

    # quit on ESC button
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:    # esc pressed
        print(bboxescoord)
        index = 0
        cap.release()

datatotnumber = whereamitot
datanumber = datatotnumber/bboxnumber
print(f"\nNUMBER OF FRAMES : {numbofframes}")
print(f"DATA MANIPULATED :{datatotnumber}")
print(f"\np1 is the list of the coordinates of the top left corner, and p2 is the width and height.")
print(f"\n\nDATA\n\n")


if bboxnumber==1:
    print(f"1:\n\np1:{bboxescoord1p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord1p2}\n\n\n")
elif bboxnumber==2:
    print(f"1:\n\np1:{bboxescoord1p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord1p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"2:\n\np1:{bboxescoord2p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord2p2}\n\n\n")
elif bboxnumber ==3:
    print(f"1:\n\np1:{bboxescoord1p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord1p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"2:\n\np1:{bboxescoord2p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord2p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"3:\n\np1:{bboxescoord3p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord1p2}\n\n\n")
elif bboxnumber==4:
    print(f"1:\n\np1:{bboxescoord1p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord1p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"2:\n\np1:{bboxescoord2p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord2p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"3:\n\np1:{bboxescoord3p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord1p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"4:\n\np1:{bboxescoord4p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord4p2}\n\n\n")
elif bboxnumber==5:
    print(f"1:\n\np1:{bboxescoord1p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord1p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"2:\n\np1:{bboxescoord2p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord2p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"3:\n\np1:{bboxescoord3p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord1p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"4:\n\np1:{bboxescoord4p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord4p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"5:\n\np1:{bboxescoord5p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord5p2}\n\n\n")
elif bboxnumber==6:
    print(f"1:\n\np1:{bboxescoord1p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord1p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"2:\n\np1:{bboxescoord2p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord2p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"3:\n\np1:{bboxescoord3p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord1p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"4:\n\np1:{bboxescoord4p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord4p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"5:\n\np1:{bboxescoord5p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord5p2}\n\n\n")
    print(f"6:\n\np1:{bboxescoord6p1}\n\np2:{bboxescoord6p2}")
else:
    print ("Can't print the lists blblblblb")
```

**EDIT**

Here is what I get from the IDLE:

```
DATA


1:

p1:[(538, 534), (541, 543), (544, 553), (546, 562), (544, 554), (541, 546), (539, 538), (536, 530), (534, 522), (531, 514), (528, 507), (526, 500), (524, 492), (521, 485), (518, 477), (516, 469), (516, 469), (513, 462), (511, 455), (508, 448), (506, 441), (503, 435), (501, 428), (498, 421), (496, 415), (494, 408), (494, 402), (493, 397), (493, 392), (491, 386), (490, 380), (490, 374), (489, 369), (488, 364), (487, 358), (486, 353), (486, 348), (484, 344), (484, 339), (483, 334), (482, 330), (481, 324), (480, 319), (480, 315), (478, 311), (478, 307), (477, 303), (476, 298), (475, 294), (474, 290), (471, 284), (470, 278), (466, 271), (469, 266), (470, 263), (471, 259), (474, 256), (475, 252), (476, 249), (476, 245)]

p2:[(561, 560), (564, 569), (567, 579), (569, 588), (567, 580), (564, 572), (562, 564), (559, 556), (557, 548), (554, 540), (551, 533), (549, 526), (547, 518), (544, 511), (541, 503), (539, 495), (539, 495), (536, 488), (534, 481), (531, 474), (529, 467), (526, 461), (524, 454), (521, 447), (519, 441), (517, 434), (517, 428), (516, 423), (516, 418), (514, 412), (513, 406), (513, 400), (512, 395), (511, 390), (510, 384), (509, 379), (509, 374), (507, 370), (507, 365), (506, 360), (505, 356), (504, 350), (503, 345), (503, 341), (501, 337), (501, 333), (500, 329), (499, 324), (498, 320), (497, 316), (494, 310), (493, 304), (489, 297), (492, 292), (493, 289), (494, 285), (497, 282), (498, 278), (499, 275), (499, 271)]



2:

p1:[(436, 539), (436, 548), (434, 558), (434, 567), (433, 576), (432, 585), (431, 595), (430, 586), (429, 578), (429, 570), (428, 561), (427, 553), (426, 545), (425, 536), (424, 528), (423, 520), (424, 520), (423, 512), (422, 503), (422, 496), (421, 488), (420, 480), (419, 473), (418, 465), (417, 458), (416, 451), (415, 443), (414, 436), (413, 429), (413, 422), (412, 416), (411, 408), (411, 401), (410, 394), (409, 388), (408, 382), (407, 376), (406, 369), (405, 362), (404, 356), (403, 350), (403, 344), (402, 339), (401, 333), (400, 327), (400, 321), (398, 316), (398, 310), (397, 305), (396, 301), (398, 296), (401, 292), (403, 288), (406, 284), (408, 280), (411, 277), (413, 273), (416, 269), (418, 266), (420, 262)]

p2:[(456, 553), (456, 562), (454, 572), (454, 581), (453, 590), (452, 599), (451, 609), (450, 600), (449, 592), (449, 584), (448, 575), (447, 567), (446, 559), (445, 550), (444, 542), (443, 534), (444, 534), (443, 526), (442, 517), (442, 510), (441, 502), (440, 494), (439, 487), (438, 479), (437, 472), (436, 465), (435, 457), (434, 450), (433, 443), (433, 436), (432, 430), (431, 422), (431, 415), (430, 408), (429, 402), (428, 396), (427, 390), (426, 383), (425, 376), (424, 370), (423, 364), (423, 358), (422, 353), (421, 347), (420, 341), (420, 335), (418, 330), (418, 324), (417, 319), (416, 315), (418, 310), (421, 306), (423, 302), (426, 298), (428, 294), (431, 291), (433, 287), (436, 283), (438, 280), (440, 276)]



3:

p1:[]

p2:[(561, 560), (564, 569), (567, 579), (569, 588), (567, 580), (564, 572), (562, 564), (559, 556), (557, 548), (554, 540), (551, 533), (549, 526), (547, 518), (544, 511), (541, 503), (539, 495), (539, 495), (536, 488), (534, 481), (531, 474), (529, 467), (526, 461), (524, 454), (521, 447), (519, 441), (517, 434), (517, 428), (516, 423), (516, 418), (514, 412), (513, 406), (513, 400), (512, 395), (511, 390), (510, 384), (509, 379), (509, 374), (507, 370), (507, 365), (506, 360), (505, 356), (504, 350), (503, 345), (503, 341), (501, 337), (501, 333), (500, 329), (499, 324), (498, 320), (497, 316), (494, 310), (493, 304), (489, 297), (492, 292), (493, 289), (494, 285), (497, 282), (498, 278), (499, 275), (499, 271)]
```

Comment: Is ```python-bouncing-ball-simulator-5_V9F95rFx_JQ0y(1).mp4``` a separate video which it has to load?

Comment: @Sujay Yes it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after reading it almost 3 times I understood.
Using lists which had siblings names wasn't a good thing to do same if I can't do it in an otherway, I was just printing an other list x3